# ManyToOne and Column Conflict

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one, identity-column

error :  @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: com.spring.mysql.test.api.model.Lancamentos.categoria

```
    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name="id_categoria")
    private Categoria categoria;
```

Comment: Please post the code you are executing, what you try to achieve and the exception including the full stack trace.

Comment: please provide more context and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @JoinColumn instead of @Column.